# asp.net cant see website in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am totally new in asp.net and c#, just startet today, but i've already hit the first stupid problem!

I've uploaded af file Default.cshtml to my server, but when I try it in the browser i get "You don't have permission to access /asptest/ on this server", and when I try specific to open Default.cshtml in the browser, i just see the code of my file..

So far the file contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>ASP.TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What could I do wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Have you built the application?

Comment: No I don't think so, just made a file containing the written above, called Default.cshtml... What do you mean by build the application? links would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebPages requires a BOM on UTF-8 pages or it won't read the page as UTF-8. And if it doesn't do that, it won't output a UTF-8 encoded page.

This isn't an ASP.NET issue, but rather a WebPages issue. WebPages processes the real page, and it doesn't interpret the html to know that it should be UTF-8. The only way it knows is by looking for a BOM.

Please add `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />` to your config file.